# Tests behind comparison of a sample's survival to that of the general population

Tags: survival, epidemiology

In the literature there are often reports of comparisons of a sample's survival to that of the general population. Life and mortality tables are cited however the tests and statistical procedures behind this comparison are not.

How is this comparison performed? Which tests, procedures and calculations are involved?

I am familiar with this question [Compare survival of one population to the general population](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20777/compare-survival-of-one-population-to-the-general-population) but it does not answer my question. I am seeking more details.